# I killed Flowey and reloaded my save file, but he's still not there!

Tags: undertale

I killed Flowey after a pacifist run and then, realizing that I now could not get true pacifist, I reloaded my save file. But Flowey wasn't there. I did this a few more times, and eventually I just reset, but Flowey still wasn't there. Help?

Comment: @Virusbomb I think the OP wants Flowey returned in their current game, not a new game..

Comment: which happens to be impossible without meticulous game deconstruction and frankly it's easier just to remove the save

Answer (score -2):

undertale has like a "safe save" it records stuff even if you reload a save file, so people wouldnt do stuff like that, i remember a youtube video explaining that, there is even an easter egg with flowey too using that "save" system, i may be wrong, but i remember something in those lines

Comment: Could you provide a link to the YouTube video you mention?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMD62c0VOQc here

Comment: Hey @GabrielC. please enter the necessary information into the answer itself. It makes the answer itself more useful and in case the video might disappear from YouTube in the unknown future, your answer will still be valid.